# With localhost running on my desktop right now,can i view it on my android phone(samsung/lg etc)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localhost, android-networking

i have an app(ruby on rails) running great on my desktop(localhost) which can recognize a request from a browser/mobile phone.Can i check it on my mobile phone too,without using android emulator.Just by hitting my ip will help me out????

Answer (score 1):

`rails s` is by default binding to all interfaces on your desktop.
So if you know the IP address of your desktop (look it up in `ifconfig`) you can simply use that IP to access the Rails application.

eg: `http://192.168.0.100:3000`.

You then inspect the user-agent to find out it's a mobile phone or not.

Comment: Anyway I would suggest `thin` webserver, since WeBrick is somehow slow for remote connections.

Comment: Is webrick not siutable for mobile app...By the word **thin**,what does it main???@Tomáš Dundáček

Comment: well i tried from opera browser from my mobile device,i am getting error as **Cannot connect to the remote server**...@Tigraine

Comment: Is your mobile phone connected to your WiFi?

Comment: no ..it has a 3G connection and i can see google homepage too..@Tigraine

Comment: You need to connect your Phone to your *local network* in order to be able to connect to your desktop by IP address. 3G won't work.

Comment: i am in my office..so is there a case that my office's proxy may be a obstacle between my mobile app and the server OR may be some other reason..should i try it in my home instead...@Tigraine

Comment: yes im hitting at http://192.168.0.100:3000...for example ...on port 3000..still the same error..i found the ip from my host file entry..@Tigraine

Comment: What does it mean by connecting my phone to a local network..how can i do that..(using USB)...@Tigraine

Answer (score 1):

The rails server can be started with the `b` flag which specifies the IP address you want to use:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

deploy your app to heroku or AWS and use git to maintain your app code...Then you can connect to your phone using internet

Comment: right now,without worrying about the deployment..can i access it on my phone..if yes than HOW????@polurupraveen

Comment: You have to connect your phone to your local network..
I repeat local network not internet

Comment: thanks for the reply..but   
What does it mean by connecting my phone to a local network..how can i do that..(using USB).???..@polurupraveen